# Why won't Eclipse auto-suggest methods (content assist) in certain parts of my source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I have a piece of code like this:

```
// content assist works here
sitesGrid.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {
    // content assist doesn't work in here
    public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
        // content assist doesn't work in here
    }
});
// content assist works here
```

It seems that content assist doesn't work if I'm inside a `new Object()`'s class body. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: to clarify, typing an object's identifier followed by a period will normally suggest methods that can be run on that object. This does not work in the specified locations of my source code. (ex: type `new String().` and wait for a fraction of a second. A menu of `String`'s methods will appear, allowing you to select one.)

Comment: Can you tell us a little more specifically what doesn't work?

Comment: @Keppil, typing an object's identifier followed by a period will normally suggest methods that can be run on that object. This does not work in the specified locations of my source code.

Comment: I know what content assist is. Are you trying to make Eclipse suggest methods on `event` or some other variable/identifier?

Comment: @Keppil, I can't get content assist for *anything*, even things like `new String().`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using anonymous classes. Normally when content assist doesn't work, it is because of a syntax error somewhere, you don't have any of those?

Comment: Nope, no syntax errors. This behavior is consistent throughout my source code.

Comment: I have a very similar problem.  Content assist stopped working in some of my classes (not working in one class, but working in another class in the same package).  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Aurand, I did not find a solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the content assist is working fine but you are getting different experience because of the inner class.

**Please note** : `new RecordClickHandler() {......}` block is an inline implementation of the `RecordClickHandler` and it doesn't have same same level of visibility of the outer class attributes/methods.

Comment: Yes, but I can't get content assist for *anything*, even things like `new String().` ... Does this make sense?

Comment: I just tried and failed to reproduce the behaviour (or lack thereof) you're describing.

Comment: String str = new String(...) should work and it seems to be working for me.